# How to make this dictionary comprehension more readable

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, human-readable

I'm wondering how to rewrite this to make it more readable, so I and perhaps others can understand it without any confusion in the future:

```
d1 = {'a':True, 'b':False, 'c':True}
d2 = {'a':False, 'b':True, 'c':True}
# wanted output: False if either value is False, True only if both are True
# d3 = {'a':False, 'b':False, 'c':True}

d3 = {key: (d1[key] and d2[key]) for key in d1}
```

I'm not looking for the most possible verbose version, but just what is clear and human readable.

Comment: What's unreadable about what you have?

Comment: Looks fine as it is to me!

Comment: Possibly best way to do it :D

Comment: You can make it any more readable by using more meaningful variable names

Answer (score 2):

What you've got looks very human-readable to me. You could probably **rename** the three dictionaries to be more descriptive of their purpose, but that's about it. I think about the only way you're going to make it clearer is to expand it into an explicit loop.

```
# This would be so much nicer with real variable names, don't you agree?
d1_AND_d2 = {}
for key in d1:
    d1_AND_d2[key] = d1[key] and d2.get(key) # Use get in case d1 has more keys.
```

Comment: Let's call `d3` `d1ANDd2`...

Comment: @Floris I like it :-D

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it with itertools and got something utterly less readable:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

d1 = {'a':True, 'b':False, 'c':True}
d2 = {'a':False, 'b':True, 'c':True}

key = itemgetter(0)
value = itemgetter(1)

d3 = {key: all(map(value, values))
      for key, values in groupby(sorted(d1.items() + d2.items()), key)}
```

I find your version a whole lot more readable.

(I know that's not exactly what you asked for, but that's what I came up with while trying to give a real answer and needed to share it with someone.)

Comment: I can't really upvote it, but I will give you a smiley for effort:  \^-^/

Comment: @Floris I take a bow and thank you.